# C# Local datagridview upload to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a bit of a problem. I am loading a `.CSV` file's contents into a `DataGridView` to locally edit rows whilst the our network is offline.

Once the network comes online again, I need to be able run update or insert from a local datagridview to take the contents to the SQL Server and update those rows that already exist.

At the moment I'm using a `SqlBulkCopy` however I cannot edit records on application once this has uploaded as it tries to add a new record and the database obviously throws back a PK constraint breach.

Any ideas?

Comment: bulk copy the records to an empty table and then kick off a stored procedure that does the insert/update to your final table.

Comment: Any other ideas without using a stored procedure or that just the nature of a DataGridView

Comment: No other ideas that involve SqlBulkCopy.  You can use SSIS instead which will let you do a merge-update during the load process.

Comment: Any ideas on how I would go about that because I've never used SSIS before. Also the I dont have to use SqlBulkCopy if you have a better idea.

Comment: If you google "SSIS Upsert" you will find tutorials.